# Rendering stars in 3D space - AbsMag to OpenGL scale values

Tags: absolute-magnitude

I am using the AMNH's [Digital Universe](https://www.amnh.org/research/hayden-planetarium/digital-universe) stars.speck file to render stars in 3D space. The speck contains parsec-scale coortinates, where our Sun is at 0,0,0. It also lists the AbsMag values - i.e the luminosity from 10 parsecs away. I want to now scale my star textures in openGL, so the resulting star sizes are accurate. How could I convert the AbsMag inverse logarithmic scale to a scale value of 0-infinity, where 0.0 means the star goes away, and 1.0 is no change? Obviously can't make the Sun stay at 1, as that would make it huge.

Comment: I'm working on a similar project in JavaScript using Three.js (feel free to contact me if you'd like to collaborate), and have run into the same issue. Drawing stars with accurate brightness makes them look unusual. Most star charts use different sizes to indicate different magnitudes, instead of the star's actual angular diameter (which is effectively zero for all stars excluding the sun). Our eyes view stars as points, but stars show up as circles in pictures for this interesting reason: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/92387/why-do-stars-appear-as-circles-not-points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Accurate star size" is a problem. Obviously you do not have the resolution on your screen for accurate angular resolution of stars (they would require an absurdly fine resolution), and the dynamic range of brightness is also too low -- stars range over many orders of magnitude in brightness, far more than a screen can show. Deeply annoying. What one might want to do is to make each star have a brightness and screen size that is proportional to their actual brightness in the sky to give the same feeling as the sky would give. This is still very tough, since screens have different [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction). To top it off, the human eye actually has a pretty logarithmic response to light (this is why magnitudes and gamma correction make sense).

Here is a rough idea. A star with AbsMag of $M$ has an actual luminosity of $$L = L_\odot 10^{0.4(M_\odot - M)}$$ where $L_\odot$ is the luminosity of the sun and $M_\odot$ is the absolute magnitude of the sun. Things get easy if we just count luminosity in terms of $L_\odot$, making the sun one unit of luminosity.

A spot of radius $r$ on the screen with luminance $l$ radiates power as $P=\pi r^2 l$. That luminance is due to the gamma-corrected luma value $V$ the computer displays: $l = K V^\gamma$.

Assuming the radius changes with luminosity too as $r(L)$, I would try $r(L)=r_0 L^a$ where $a\approx 0.6$ (but this is guesswork) and the sun has radius $r_0$ pixels.

So trying to put this together, we get the pixel brightness as $$V = V_0 (L/ r(L)^2)^{1/\gamma} = V'_0 L^{(1-2a)/\gamma}$$ where $V_0$ and $V'_0$ are the pixel brightnesses used for the sun in this model. Basically this squashes the actual luminosity with $a$ (representing using bigger spots for brighter stars, not requiring as intense pixels) and $\gamma$ (to correct for the screen and the eye). What values to use will largely be trial and error unless you want to try to use screen photometry equipment.

So the full formula converting from absolute magnitude to pixel value would be: $$V = V_0 10^{0.4(4.83 - M)(1-2a)/\gamma}.$$

Comment: A comment on my answer: it is often a matter of taste what one likes to see, so making the parameters a and gamma controllable by the keyboard (like in Celestia) is a good idea.

Comment: I'll try and see where that gets me to..

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but may help explain why displaying stars with accurate angular diameters is a bad idea.

Per https://www.eso.org/public/usa/news/eso9706/ the star with the largest angular diameter is R Doradus at 0.057 arcseconds which translates to about 1/63158th of a degree.

Even if you used a "tight" 9 degree view for your canvas, 0.057 seconds would take up only 1/568421 of the screen width. In other words, your image would have to be at least 284211 pixels for the star to be 0.5 pixel wide, the smallest amount you could reasonably round up to 1 pixel.

Even our eyes don't see stars this way, or the night sky would appear completely black (excluding the moon, planets, and Earth-generated light of course).

As good an idea as it seems, display stars as their actual size is a bad idea because that's now cameras or even our own eyes see them.